# How to give instructions to a backgroundWorker and process the results right?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, backgroundworker

My winform application communicates with an external device via USB. For the Communication between my application the device I use a backgroundWorker. This way I can guarantee, that only one communication takes place at a time. 
I am using e.argument to give instructions to the bW like this: `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync("TASKX")` and the e.Result value to pass the result to the main application. 
There are a lot of tasks, and since I have to handle each result for each task different I get lot of cases in my RunWorkerCompleted Function.

Here is a shema of the code I use inside the bW_DoWork function:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  if((string)e.Argument="TASK1")
  {
    //do something
    if(result==1)
      e.Result = "TASK1_RESULT1";
    if(result==2)
      e.Result = "TASK1_RESULT2";
    //...
  }
  else if((string)e.Argument="TASK2")
  {
    //do something
    if(result == 1)
      e.Result = "TASK2_RESULT1";
    //...
  }
  //and so on...
}
```

And here is what the code in my bW_RunWorkerCompleted lookes like:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        //handle cancelation
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //handle error
    }
    else
    {
      //handle all cases
      if(e.Result=="TASK1_RESULT1)
      //and so on...        
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a better or cleaner way to give the bW instructions or should I use a completly different solution.

Comment: Well, don't do *that*.  The type of e.Argument is *object*.  So it can be *any* object, including a poco class that has multiple properties of any type.  And you can use a lambda expression to run a worker method with any arguments.  And you can access all of the variables of the enclosing class, even the private ones, as long as you do so in a thread-safe way.  All of it better than a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1. How would it look like using a lambda expression; 2. Is it a good idea to define a List with instructions in the enclosing class and make the bW work them off?

Comment: backgroundWorker1.DoWork += (s, ea) => DoRealWork(a, b, c, d, e);